# Change style UITabBarController in iOS7

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I would like to add a default screen on a Tab Bar controller, so always load default. Currently I have had to add a Home tab which is loaded by default as the first, but it breaks my design aesthetics.

How I can upload a picture or a viewcontroller Tab Bar Controller, if you default you can not associate any kind. M par implement code?.

Comment: My actual tab bar is http://pbrd.co/1eryzJy, but i would like this http://pbrd.co/1eryIN6 in the same screen, not in the first tab show a image.

Comment: I can resolved put UITabBar object in ViewController and defined method, instead to use UITabBarController